# Proving that $S$ is a sphere

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, surfaces

Continuing on my path to learn differential geometry, I need help with the following exercise from the theory of surfaces:

> Consider the surface $S : \vec x = \vec x(u, v) \in C^3$ where
>
> $$\vec n_u = a(u, v) \vec x_u, \quad \vec n_v = a(u, v) \vec x_v \tag{*}$$
>
> and $a(u, v) \in C^2$ is a nonvanishing function. Show that $S$ is a sphere.

We use $\vec x(u, v)$ to denote the parametric representation of the surface $S$ with parameters $u$ and $v$ and it's partial derivatives by $\vec x_u = \frac{\partial \vec x}{\partial u}$ and $\vec x_v = \frac{\partial \vec x}{\partial v}$. Also, we denote by $\vec n$ the unit normal vector to the surface at a point $P$. Finally, a surface $S$ is said to be of class $C^n$ if it has partial derivatives of all orders to $n$.

---

My first thought was to prove that the position vector at a random point of the surface has constant norm but, considering the informations we're given, I don't think this is possible. I think I'm missing some key points about the properties of a sphere. Obviously the equations $(*)$ are important, but I don't see why.

Comment: Can you define the symbols?  What are $u, v, \vec{x}_{u}$, etc.?

Comment: two comments: 1. what do you mean by $n_u$, $n_v$ and $C^n$? 2. The position vector of a point on a sphere does not necessarily have constant norm, consider the case where the sphere does not have the origin as its center. However, $S$ is a sphere if and only if there is some $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and an $r \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $||x-a||=r$ if and only if $x \in S$. Of course, if you prove the norm is constant you have $S$ is a sphere centered at the origin.

Comment: I edited my original post and defined the symbols as requested. @M.Van You are correct. My reasoning can only be correct if the sphere is centered at the origin. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step I: $a$ is constant.

Differentiate the first with respect to $v$.
$$N_{uv}=a_vx_u+ax_{uv}$$ and the second with respect to $u$,

$$N_{vu}=a_ux_v+ax_{vu}.$$

Since mixed partials are equal we have

$$a_vx_u=a_ux_v$$ but since $x_u$ and $x_v$ are independent, $a_u=a_v=0$.

Step II $y=x-\frac{1}{a}n$ is constant.

Step III $|x-y|=\frac{1}{a}$.

Note that if $a=0$ you get a plane.

Comment: You've been a great help these last 24 hours, thanks! Although I understand   step I perfectly well, I not sure I understand your reasoning in step II and III. Is $y=x-\frac{1}{a}n$ the equation of the normal line to the surface? Would you mind explaining these steps?

Comment: Yeah they are totally easy $y$ is a new vector I am defining, differentiate it wrt $u$ and $v$ to get zero.  III is even more trivial, $N$ is a unit vector. Basically $y$ is the vector from the coordinate origin to the centre of the sphere.

Comment: Note that the radius of the sphere is $\frac{1}{a}$, so $a$ is the curvature.

Comment: Everything makes perfect sense now! Still don't know how I missed step III. Since we're ne supposed to repeatedly say "thanks" I'm going to go with "you're cool!" ;)

Comment: Thanks, its my pleasure really.